# Show that every eigenvalue of f is an eigenvalue of f*?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let V be a finite-dimensional vector space over an algebraically closed field K. Let
f : V → V be a linear map. Let f* : V* → V* be its dual

Show that every eigenvalue of f is an eigenvalue of f*?

Comment: Please mention your effort about the problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

Because the determinant of a matrix is invariant under taking transpose.

Comment: This is a rather good hint...but as it is written I think is rather obscure and mysterious...

Comment: @DonAntonio Perhaps you are right. But if the OP has put enough effort in the problem, then (s)he should have reviewed the relevant things (s)he has learnt: eigenvalues vs determinants, linear maps vs matrices, basis vs dual basis, etc., which should then indicate how the solution goes. In view that little or no effort was shown in the original question, I think it's OK to leave this answer as so.

Comment: You've got a point there. +1